# "None" added to list when input search does not match

Tags: python, list, dictionary

trying to complete a project shopping cart. I show available items then ask how many items required, then ask to input each item by name, which get added to cart. problem is when input does not match an item the code blows up. Im guessing i need maybe an if statement somewhere but struggling to figure it out. this also my first ever post so be gentle with me haha. Code below

```
inven = {"eggs" : 1.99, "bacon" : 2.99, "bread" : 1.99}
basket = list()
purchase_list = list()
print("Items available to purchase")
print(inven)
n = int(input("how many items do you wish to buy?"))


for i in range(n):
    b = input("type item")
    a = (inven.get(b))
    basket.append(a)
    purchase_list.append(b)
    print(purchase_list)
    print("Items in basket" + str(purchase_list))

total = sum(basket)
print("Basket Total is: £", "%.2f" % total)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for

```
b = input("type item")
a = inven.get(b)
if a and b:
    basket.append(a)
    purchase_list.append(b)
```

Note that you do not need the parentheses around the `.get()` line.

Answer (score 0):

`a = inven.get(b)` Is a nice way to get the item in the dictionary but what happens when it cant find the item you specified?

The function returns `None` so you need to catch this and put a conditional statement around your code that pushes the items onto the list.

I would also recommend changing your variable names such as `a` and `b`.

Comment: wud u use an if statement then to try and catch the None value if it cant find the specified item?

Comment: I would indeed.